# saving a FlowDocument to disk as an XPS document

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, flowdocument, xpsdocument

now the Window containing the FlowDocumentReader which contains my FlowDocument that I want to convert is loaded on the screen , it has a button there , I want when clicking on this button , to save my FLowDocument to disk as an XPS , using Package and Stream .NET classes and not using a printer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will find your answer here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/fyuan/convert-xaml-flow-document-to-xps-with-style-multiple-page-page-size-header-margin

Comment: The link is dead now. Thanks.

Comment: Edited broken link, hope I found the new one correctly.